# Clear Sugar database table column records after every start

Tags: android, database, listview, sugarorm

I have a listview with some name and url.. After my app starts I check if there is any record in my local database First clear my old records then fill table columns with listview data and if there isn't just insert data... this is how I'm doing it :

```
        List<LocalProduct> allAuthors = LocalProduct.listAll(LocalProduct.class);
    if (allAuthors == null) {
        for (int allList=0;allList<adapter.getCount();allList++){
            Product my = adapter.getItem(allList);
            String offline_name = my.name.toString().trim();
            String offline_url = my.image_url.toString().trim();
            LocalProduct book = new LocalProduct(offline_name, offline_url);
            book.save();
            }
        }else {
            allAuthors.clear(); //I tried this
            allAuthors.removeAll(allAuthors); //And this
        for (int allList=0;allList<adapter.getCount();allList++){
            Product my = adapter.getItem(allList);
            String offline_name = my.name.toString().trim();
            String offline_url = my.image_url.toString().trim();
            LocalProduct book = new LocalProduct(offline_name, offline_url);
            book.save();
            }
        }
```

But my table records are still storing same records after every start ..
What is the correct way !?

Comment: If you would like to post an answer over and above the additional answer, please post it as an answer below. We ask that answers are not merged into [solved] questions here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Insert this line before intialize LocalProduct class list:

```
SugarRecord.deleteAll(LocalProduct.class);
```

Example:

```
SugarRecord.deleteAll(LocalProduct.class);
List<LocalProduct> allAuthors = LocalProduct.listAll(LocalProduct.class);
```

Comment: You can also use this line.
LocalProduct.deleteAll(LocalProduct.class);

Comment: check this link : http://satyan.github.io/sugar/getting-started.html#usage

Comment: Yeah , it will delete my records , but column ids are still increasing

Comment: column ids are always increasing.
if you are delete table that it will start from one index

Answer (score 0):

`clear()` and `removeAll()` only remove item from `List` (which is in memory when loaded) not remove record in database.

If you want to clear record in database you need to use :

```
db.delete(TABLE_NAME, null, null);
```

Comment: What is db and TABLE_NAME , this is auto generated by Sugar orm

Comment: I dont know Sugar orm. But if it is sqlite record. You can delete record excute Sql to delete record. TABLE_NAME is name of table that you want to delete all records i, db is present of your database. More about : https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html